# Plain text markup with programable extentions point?

Tags: markdown, markup, restructuredtext

I look for plain text markup what allow extension of syntax through standard way and ability to include/program own writers (or register routines to writer extension points) in order to get final document in different form with handling additional syntax myself.

As I know **markdown** is limited to making text strong/emphasis...

**RST** look promising but I afraid that with my limited experience I miss some rich and useful markup language... I just look to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_document_markup_languages and get lost.

**PS**. For dev docs and personal blog generation.

**PPS**. *Explain why XML, JSON or any of a number of generalized markup languages doesn't meet your requirements*

Using Json or XML are not pleased because I want readability of original source format. While I work with DocBook - it is not a funny format for personal blog articles... It must be fun to write... So I look sfor some wiki syntax with extension points and engine which can provide AST.

Comment: Explain why XML, JSON or any of the other well-known, generalized, customizable markup languages don't meet your requirements.  If you're looking for a markup language specific to documents, there are [plenty of those](https://www.openoffice.org/xml/general.html) to choose from.

Comment: What about Latex?  If you need to be able to read the markup without converting it to a readable format, Markdown is probably your best bet.

Comment: LaTeX looks interesting. Is it possible to get HTML output ready for home page or blog post?

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you open a question so I put answer (that I got after studying different suggestion)?